# How can I implement a method that change directly the value this with dart extension?

Tags: dart

I want to know how can I change/affect the value of `this` with dart extensions without returning a value.

For example, when I do this :

```
"example text".cutFirstLetter();
```

by just executing it, I want its `String` value for the rest of the code to be "e", I don't want it to be returned in function, I want the whole of it to change.

let me more explain :

```
extension ExmapleExtension on String {
    String cutFirstLetter() {
        return this.substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

this will work only as returned value, so it will work on places that expect the return such as `print("example text".cutFirstLetter());` or if I assigned to another `String` such as `String newExampleText = "example text".cutFirstLetter();`

I want when I just call it in a line, it will execute it on the `this` referred `String`

I tried something like:

```
extension ExmapleExtension on String {
    removeTletter() {
        this = this.substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

but it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, strings are immutable.  Perhaps you've noticed there are no methods in the `String` class that change the value of the string "in-place".  They all return values (often other Strings).

Second, you cannot assign to `this`, only call methods on it.

So you'll have to be happy with just returning a new value.

Comment: Understood, is only String in immutable or all data types in dart like integers, doubles, Set... ?

Comment: nums are also immutable, but collections are not.  You can create immutable objects through the use of getters or final members.